# PasswordVault Windows Phone equivalent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, windows-8

Is there an equivalent to Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault (Windows 8) in Windows Phone 7 and if not what is the best way to achieve something similar to this? Would AES or XOR encryption to local settings suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to encrypt data, then store it in the isolated storage. It should be safe enough for your passwords.